# Failed to add new user to existing Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

At our company we are experimenting with the Google App Engine.
There is already an app online and they wanted to add me to this existing app.
We tried to do this several times but I still can't access the existing app.

The email you receive when you are added to an existing app consists of 2 links.
- one for coupling it to an existing Google account
- one for coupling it to the receiving email address which is a Google Account

If i follow the link in case 1, I'm redirected to a page where I need to create a new application.

If i follow the link in case 2, I get the following Server Error:
"Sorry, you've reached a login page for a domain that isn't using Google Apps. Please check the web address and try again."

If one of my colleagues looks at the Permissions page of all users, my status is pending...

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your accounts are on Google Apps? if is the case, you need to use the good link; In the email you received you should have 2 links to validate account. The first is for google account and the second is for google apps account.